# How to correct an LLC Entity Name in California?

Tags: business

I recently purchased an LLC via LegalZoom and they made a mistake by adding a comma in my LLC Name. I was told that I had to cough up over $150 just to get it corrected through them so I wanted to do it on my own as the filing fee is only $30 or $45 if I wanted to drop it off.

The form is located here: http://bpd.cdn.sos.ca.gov/llc/forms/llc-11.pdf

My issue is that I don't know what some of these fields are for. What do I put in "4. Parties to the Document Being Corrected" and in "Document Provision"?

For the parties to the document being corrected, I assumed it would be LegalZoom, Inc. but maybe it's the Secretary of State? Not sure what to put in that field and if I am even allowed to correct it.

Current LLC is "Company, LLC", want it corrected to "Company LLC".

Comment: LegalZoom is charging you for *their* mistake?

Comment: @phoog Sadly yes, they won't own up to their mistake though, they just said it's what it says on their Questionnaire that I filled out but I remember removing the comma.

Comment: Although I have never filled out such a form, here is my best guess, for the parties part, put down every entity listed on the original form, yourself, anyone else with stake in your llc and generally anyone included in the original paperwork (assuming legal zoom has provided you with that), if they didn't just put down all the names you definitely know were on the document. For the provision part, just indicate what part of the form is wrong (wouldn't hurt to cite the form number and box number) and indicate what's wrong about it, in the next part (7) put the right spelling.

Comment: @Viktor Thanks for your response, come to think of it, I believe I have to fill out this form instead: http://bpd.cdn.sos.ca.gov/llc/forms/llc-2.pdf I think form LLC-11 is for the organizer (LegalZoom) rather than me to fill out as it states at the bottom before signing: "This form must be signed in the same manner in which the document being corrected was required to be signed."